# A single word for "in the process of being replaced"

Tags: single-word-requests

Context:

> If a practice is obsolete, it may be in the process of being replaced.

Please provide a single word for "in the process of being replaced".

Comment: Won't *replacement* do?

Comment: If you're looking for an adjective, try *obsolescent*.

Comment: I suspect there is no such word. What's wrong with *"undergoing replacement"*?

Comment: Sometimes I say that a practice is "fading from use" or "waning" or "is less favored."

Answer (score 3):

*Preempt* has one definition meaning to take the place of; displace

Then there are also these synonyms:

*supersede*: 1. To take the place of; replace.
2. To cause to be set aside, especially to displace as inferior or antiquated.

*supplant*: To displace and substitute for (another); this term seems to be replacement through scheming or force

The noun forms would be *preemption*, *supersedure*, and *supplantation*.

The second definition of *supersedure* is interesting. From Merriam Webster: 1. The act or process of superseding.
2. Replacement of a queen bee that has grown old or weak by one that is younger or more vigorous.

I learned something new!

Comment: I like **superseded** as well, as in, "_The new process supersedes the obsolete one_." +1 for the apiarian reference; that's a honey of a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [*obsoleting*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsolete) or *obsolescent* (as @Robusto suggests) is what you're looking for?

> Usage notes:
>
> To obsolete is often used in computing and other technical fields to indicate an effort to remove or replace something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't very well replace a passive construction with a single word here. If you want an alternative to *replace*, you may want to consider *oust*.

Answer (score 0):

"[Deprecated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecated)" in the sense of "permitted but not approved of or recommended", carries this concept by implication, and may or may not suit depending upon you precise circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently, a null phrase is a suitable replacement for *in the process of*.  The example "If a practice is obsolete, it may be in the process of being replaced" becomes "If a practice is obsolete, it may be being replaced".  As substitutes for *being replaced*, one has many choices, depending on intended meaning and desired level of formality.  For example, with *[transitory](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/transitory)* the example becomes "If a practice is obsolete, it may be transitory".  Also consider *in purgatory, sidestepped, for it, smoked*.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**. Hence,

> *If a practice is obsolete, it may be in the process of being replaced.*

becomes:

> *If a practice is obsolete, it may be **updated**.*

If it's important to emphasize a lengthy or drawn-out process, you could say:

> *If a practice is being replaced, it may be updated **over time**.*